# Window xp and java 8

Tags: java, java-8, windows-xp

I am making a project by java 8 but I'm confusing about can window xp run java 8 project as well, and I don't know if I use new resources of java 8, will it work in window xp like work in window 10? =)), Thanks!

Comment: isn't jre for java 8 at least windows 7? since, it never mentioned [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/install/windows_system_requirements.html). although i believe some jre 7 still works in xp.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To install `Java 8` on `Windows XP` you need the Microsoft Windows Installer (MSI). The file name of the installer has one of the following formats:

```
jre-version-x86.msi (for Windows XP 32-bit systems)

jre-version-x64.msi (for Windows XP 64-bit systems)
```

Substitute the appropriate version number for version. For example, if you using the installer for update `1.8.0_74`, the file name: `jre-version-x86.msi` would become `jre1.8.0_74_x86.msi`. You can download [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/javaclientmsiinstallers/files/v8u74/). Other versions look [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/javaclientmsiinstallers/files/).

Here the screenshots from `Windows XP`:
[image]

Java 8u131:
[image]

Work `JavaFX 8` on `Windows XP`:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Just tried this for Java 8u181 running on Windows XP SP3 in Parallels and it won't install using the `.exe` or `.msi`.  It prompts for confirmation and then just dies.  Fortunately, the version linked -- Java8u74 -- installs just fine, thanks.

Comment: @tresf  **Java 8u131** - works on XP

Comment: is Look & Feel your program used a private version or open available? it is pretty.

Comment: @DanielYeung  this  `javafx-samples` - Demos and samples by Oracle. Include `Modena` -
A sample application that demonstrates the look and feel of UI components using 
the Modena theme. It gives you the option to contrast Modena and Caspian themes, 
and explore various aspects of these themes.

Answer (score 3):

The supported platforms are [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/certconfig-2095354.html) and `windows XP` is **not present there**. I would not risk it as hotspot most probably relies on system calls that might not be present in `xp`

Answer (score 0):

Oracle Java is not free for commercial usage anymore.

These days with OpenJDK you have these options (free even for commercial usage):

- https://aws.amazon.com/corretto - sponsored by Amazon
- https://github.com/ojdkbuild/ojdkbuild - sponsored by Red Hat
- https://www.azul.com/downloads/zulu - sponsored by Azul Systems
- and more... https://github.com/akullpp/awesome-java#jvm-and-jdk